# didDeselectRowAtIndexPath not called after viewWillAppear in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, viewwillappear

I'm using a `UITableViewController` subclass with `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` set to `YES` (the default value).

How do I make changes to a deselected cell when it is automatically deselected on `viewWillAppear:`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` is not called when a cell is deselected automatically on `viewWillAppear:` in a `UITableViewController` subclass.

Use the following code to make changes to the deselected in this case:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // HACK: Need to be called before super if the selection is cleared on viewWillAppear. 
    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];
    // Change the cell
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

In general, if you use `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:`, `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` will not be called.